# My discord.js bot is having issues reacting to messages that contain a specific string

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js

I am setting up a discord bot that runs off node.js, and i want it to react to any message containing the word "chad" with a custom emote. Initializing the bot works fine. Here's the current code:

```
if(message.content === "chad"){
    message.react(message.guild.emojis.get('536738717893656587'))
  }
```

when somebody does say chad i get the error

```
(node:16724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji
```

this is weird for me because i have a similar function a few lines above, that being

```
if(message.content.indexOf("longtail") >= 0){
      message.react(message.guild.emojis.get('549871163468152832'))
  }
```

where it does just fine, i tried replicating it but it gave the same error so i think it has something to do with the specific string that i tried using for the emoji? but honestly im not sure.

Comment: did you try `message.react('536738717893656587')` and are you sure the id is correct? also try `message.react(message.guild.emojis.find('name', 'nameofyouremoji'));`

Comment: i did try ```message.react('536738717893656587')``` and i am certain the id is correct. I tried ```message.react(message.guild.emojis.find('name', 'really'));``` and it gave me the error ```(node:4764) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
(node:4764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji```

Comment: The deprecation error is just the find method, nothing to worry about. What value and type does `message.guild.emojis.get('536738717893656587')` exactly return? try `var emoji = message.guild.emojis.get('536738717893656587'); console.log(typeof emoji, emoji)`

Comment: returns "undefined undefined"

Comment: It seems like there really *is* something wrong with the id. Try to list all of guild's emoji ids like this: `console.log(message.guild.emojis.map(e=>e.id))` (should work, but I can't test this myself)

Comment: oh thank you i figured it out, turns out yes it was the id but the emote i was trying to use was on a different server. I moved the emote onto this server, found it's id, and now it works fine. thank you for your help

Comment: That's what I figured, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

As resolved in the comments, the emoji id was invalid - the emoji was in another server.

Always make sure to debug when you get these types of errors.